# Javascript Regex - Quotes to Parenthesis

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace, parentheses

I'd like to somehow replace the string sequence "*" with (*) using a regex in Javascript. Replacing things between quotes to be between opening and closing parenthesis.

For example "apple" to (apple)

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see how to ask questions that are not closed or voted down. Hint: Add input and expected output examples plus whatever code you have so far

Comment: This could give you an ides http://stackoverflow.com/q/1144783/3150943

Comment: I'm sorry I thought the * in the context of regex would be clear. I will edit the question.

Comment: Are you certain that your quoted strings won't contain escaped quotes? (`\"`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like:

```
str.replace(/"(.*?)"/g, function(_, match) { return "(" + match + ")"; })
```

Or more simply

```
str.replace(/"(.*?)"/g, "($1)")
```

Note the "non-greedy" specifier `?`. Without this, the regexp will eat up everything including double quotes up until the last one in the input. See documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-questionmark). The `$1` in the second fragment is a back-reference referring the first parenthesized group. See documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter).

Comment: This works for me thank you so much! Edit: I would accept this as the correct answer but the answer by @nu11p01n73R is more condensed. Thank you very much though.

Comment: However the regex here was correct from the start and explains why

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like

```
replace(/"(.*?)"/g, "($1)")
```

**Example**

```
"this will be \"replaced\"".replace(/"(.*)"/, "($1)")
=> this will be (replaced)

"this \"this\" will be \"replaced\"".replace(/"(.*?)"/g, "($1)")
=> this (this) will be (replaced)
```